# Get function and object pointers from std::function(std::bind)

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I have a `Command` template which is generic enough to store a pointer to an object of class `T` and a member function pointer of this class `T`:

```
template<typename T>
class Command : public CommandBase
{
public:

    typedef void (T::*MemFn)();

    Command(MemFn fun, T* receiver) :
        CommandBase(),
        MemFn(fun),
        m_receiver(receiver)
    {

    }

    void execute() const override {(m_receiver->*m_function)();}

protected:

    T* m_receiver;
    MemFn m_function;

};
```

These `Command` objects are executed by instances of class `Property`, nothing really complex here.

Up until now my `Commands` were instanciated outside of `Property`: a pointer to a `Command` was provided to the `Property` using a `Property::register()` function and the `Commands` were deleted by `Property`. That is `Commands` were created and deleted by different classes: not really clean as a design.

To clean things up I would like `Property` to both create and delete the `Commands`. So I would like to provide the pointers to the receiver and member function in argument to the register function. In order to avoid couplings I would like `Property` not to know about the type of the receiver, so I thought about providing the pointers to the receiver and member function into a std::function(std::bind()), so my Property looks like:

```
class Property
{
public:
    typedef boost::function<void ()> MemFnWrapper;

    bool register(MemFnWrapper memFnWrapper);

...
}
```

And the code doing the registration looks like:

```
Property myProp;
myProp->register(boost::bind(&myMemberFunction, this));
```

Note that this registeration process is done in an object of class `ConcreteNode`, which is the type named T in template `Command`. `ConcreteNode` define function `myMemberFunction`.

This is all very good. Now my question is: what do I put in the definition of `Property::register()`? In `register` I need to get the pointers from the receiver (`this`) and from the member function to call (`myMemberFunction`) so as to store them inside of `Command ::m_receiver` and `Command ::m_function`.

Do you have any idea how I can do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `register` is a keyword in C++.

Comment: Not sure if you considered this, by why not just have `register` take the `Command` by value, rather than a pointer? Then if the client code wants to dynamically allocate the `Command`, it can, and it is responsible for cleaning it up. `Property` then can then store its copy of the `Command` without any dynamic allocation.

Comment: You cannot decompose `std::function`. Are you sure you need all this mechanism? Why not just use `std::function` instead of `Command`?

Comment: What does `Command` do that `boost::function` does not do?  Why do you need `Command` at all?

Comment: @Kerrek: you are right, I simplified my case without thinking about the keyword. Thanks ;)

Comment: @sftrabbit: this is interesting... Not optimal in terms of performance but not so bad either as this is code which is called at initialization and not at runtime.

Comment: @Yakk & n.m.: I read that dereferencing the function call when using std::function / std::bind were very costly, up to 20ns on a modern PC. As I am going to heavily rely on the mechanism, I cannot afford such an heavy overload. Now I am not an expert and have no idea what a "normal" function call costs for example...

Comment: use `std::function`, don't optimize prematurely

Comment: @Alf: this piece of code is in my critical path for a real-time app, so I'd better watch twice...

Comment: @arennuit I would be shocked if yours is any faster than `function`: why do you think it is?

Comment: @Yakk: just because I read that `function` and `bind` imply a performance overhead. Now if you are certain that `function/bind` are not that problematic in terms of perfs, I probably need to code both solutions and benchmark...

Comment: @arennuit I am not saying they are super fast: I am saying your solution looks equally slow.

Comment: Your solution is highly likely to be slower on your machine than the std::function based one. It is slower on mine. You are encouraged to measure for yourself.